# Как по клику добавить класс?

Tags: jquery

На странице есть блок комментарий, по нажатию на кнопку `ответить` нужно показать форму, где будет вводиться ответ, если форма показана и пользователь нажал на другом комментарии кнопку `ответить`, активную форму нужно скрыть и показать в другом месте. Как это можно сделать?

```css
.comment {
  width: 100%;
}

.comment-item {
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.comment-item__text {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.comment-item__reply {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.comment-item__form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
  <div class="comment-item">
    <div class="comment-item__text">Комментарий</div>
    <div class="comment-item__reply">Ответить</div>
    <div class="comment-item__form">
      <form action="">
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="5" class="" placeholder="Ваш комментарий"></textarea>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="comment-item">
    <div class="comment-item__text">Комментарий</div>
    <div class="comment-item__reply">Ответить</div>
    <div class="comment-item__form">
      <form action="">
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="5" class="" placeholder="Ваш комментарий"></textarea>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let allCommentItem = document.querySelectorAll('.comment-item');
allCommentItem.forEach(commentItem => {
    commentItem.querySelector('.comment-item__reply').addEventListener('click', e => {
        allCommentItem.forEach(i => i.querySelector('.comment-item__form').classList.remove('visible'))
        commentItem.querySelector('.comment-item__form').classList.add('visible')
    })
})
```

```css
.comment {
  width: 100%;
}

.comment-item {
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.comment-item__text {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.comment-item__reply {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.comment-item__form {
  display: none;
}
.visible {
  display: block 
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
  <div class="comment-item">
    <div class="comment-item__text">Комментарий</div>
    <div class="comment-item__reply">Ответить</div>
    <div class="comment-item__form">
      <form action="">
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="5" class="" placeholder="Ваш комментарий"></textarea>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="comment-item">
    <div class="comment-item__text">Комментарий</div>
    <div class="comment-item__reply">Ответить</div>
    <div class="comment-item__form">
      <form action="">
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="5" class="" placeholder="Ваш комментарий"></textarea>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```